# Handling errors in an async/await Angular HttpClient method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am attempting to use an async/await pattern in order to handle a scenario that might be considered "callback hell" if implemented otherwise.

Here is an extremely dumbed down version of the code. The real code has about 5 conditional HttpClient calls based on the data from the first call (not my api...) which is the reason why I am using the async/await pattern in the first place.

```
async blah(): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
        let resp = await this.http.get("https://httpstat.us/500").toPromise();
        console.warn("you should not see this");

        // the real code will logically call the api multiple times based on conditonal data from resp
        // hence the attempted usage of async/await to avoid "callback hell"
        // blah() will eventually return an object.

        return true;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error("caught inside blah()");
        throw err;
    }
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.blah().then(data => {
        console.warn('okokokok');
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
    });
}
```

What happens, I can see the call actually 500, but the code continues and the following is printed to the console:

```
polyfills.js:3 GET https://httpstat.us/500/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
main.js:927 you should not see this
main.js:940 okokokok
```

As you can see, it isn't catching the 500 (or any other http status I have tested with)

The device I am testing with is a Pixel 2 running P and the console data is coming from a Chrome device inspector session.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

** Edit: This is clearly an issue with the combination of ionic and angular... It should work...

** Edit: it turns out to 100% be an Angular issue... Not the framework itself but how an interceptor was implemented.  I will leave this here instead of deleting the question in the rare case someone else requires it.

Comment: `blah()` is returning `true`, not the Promise.

Comment: @ChrisG not true, the method is defined as `async`, so it will always return a `Promise` (here resolving to `true`).

Comment: Your code is working ok, tested in stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uj6kq5). Maybe some ionic issue?

Comment: Just a guess - what rxjs version do you use? If you use something older, you will need to import `toPromise` operator (for v6 its already there).

Comment: @MartinAdámek I am currently using "rxjs": "5.5.8"...

Comment: So that should be fine, from v5.5+ you do not need to import that. Can you try replicating your problem in stackblitz? Are you really able to replicate with given minimal example, maybe you oversimplified it?

Comment: @MartinAdámek I actually wrote that in the app itself and copied and pasted the code and responses here :D It's legit.  The stackblitz you created works exactly as I would expect it to... just doesn't work that way inside this ionic app :D

Comment: @MartinAdámek i tried moving the code from ionViewDidLoad() to the constructor and there was no change.  I built a stackblitz using the ionic template and once I added the "toPromise" import (that template uses rxjs < 5.5) it worked as expected.  The only difference is that my code resides in an 'ionic page' which is structured like @Component({
    selector: "some-selector",
    templateUrl: "some-template.html"
})
export class SomePage {....}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180527/discussion-between-nokturnal-and-martin-adamek).

Comment: @MartinAdámek it turns out to 100% be an Angular issue... Not the framework itself but how an interceptor was implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If i uderstood your question correctly, you want to do cascade calls, so you make the http request and based on the response you want to do another http call. If that is the case, then you should consider using `switchMap` operator:

`this.http.get("https://httpstat.us/500").pipe(
  switchMap( result => {
    if(result.a === 5) {
       return this.http.get("some server api url");
    }
    return return this.http.get("another server api url");
  })
)`

You handle the errors then in `rxjs` way.

See [cascading calls](https://chrisnoring.gitbooks.io/rxjs-5-ultimate/content/cascading-calls.html)

Comment: I have edited my question slightly.  The subsequent calls to the API are sometimes conditional based on data from the previous calls... Can that be accomplished via the pipe and switchMap combo?

Comment: see the update. question is if the subsequent calls will fetch data in same structure, if not then your observable will be union of types, like `Observable<A | B>`

Comment: I'll give it a shot since I cannot get this async + toPromise() call to work at all in my scenario... It makes no sense!